# Trying to create a text file using TS and HTML5

Tags: html, typescript, html5-filesystem

In my app I'm receiving a `string` which needs to be saved to the local machine. I', reading [this](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/#toc-direntry) guide (html5 filesystem tutorial). The problem I have to use TS ("typescript": "2.6.1") and looks like part of the API is not supported. The following line gives me two errors:

```
  window.requestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY, 1024*1024, onInitFs, this.errorHandler);
```

first:

```
[ts] Property 'requestFileSystem' does not exist on type 'Window'.
```

second:

```
[ts] Property 'TEMPORARY' does not exist on type 'Window'.
```

Any workaround or an updated documentation? PS I'm aware this is supported only in Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This API is currently only [supported in Chrom](https://caniuse.com/#search=requestFileSystem) and does not work in other browsers. If you are using Chrome however, you have to use the **prefixed** version of this function which is `webkitRequestFileSystem`:

```
var requestFileSystem = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
```

The support also goes for `window.TEMPORARY`.

Now, if you want to create a file and write some content in it, you have to create a so-called writer object:

```
function onInitFs(fs) {
  fs.root.getFile('my-file.txt', {create: true}, function(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.createWriter(function(fileWriter) {
      fileWriter.onwriteend = function(e) {
        ...
      };

      fileWriter.onerror = function(e) {
        ...
      };

      var blob = new Blob(['Content that goes into the file'], {type: 'text/plain'});

      fileWriter.write(blob);
    }, errorHandler);
  }, errorHandler);
}

requestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY, 1024*1024, onInitFs, errorHandler);
```

For more information on the `FileSystemFileEntry` API check out [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystemFileEntry).